# how should @2x and -568h@2x images be different from usual ones

Tags: ios, objective-c

If I'm writing an iPhone app, I have to use `"@2x"` suffix for devices with retina display and `"@-568h@2x"` for iPhone 5 apps. How should these images differ? Should I make the image with double length and height (80x40 -> 160x80)? And what about `"-568h@2x"`? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, images for retina displays are double the size of normal ones, so as you said, if you have a 80x40 image, the 2x version should be 160x80.

As for the 568, same width but the height you want to appear in a iPhone5 screen. This image is not mandatory, you can use the same image for retina screens for iPhone4 and iPhone5, this is just in case you want to have different ones, for example for the splash screen.

Comment: It also used to be the only way to make the app aware of the iPhone 5's bigger height so that auto layout would work.